# I want to make a simple video sharing site. Where should I start?

Tags: javascript, html, video

So I want to make a video sharing site like Youtube or Daily Motion. I know it will not be famous but I want to make it specific about a topic so more people int interested will visit. So I know Javascript, Html, Html5, SQL. I am having one problem (or maybe two). I want to make a page where the user write his name, video title, description, and an .mp4 link for the video (I have an idea to make them get an .mp4 link) and when he press "publish", a html page automatically generates with the following:

```
<html>
<head>Scripts bla bla bla</head>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

And here comes the next problem: I want the source "movie.mp4" to be taken from the database, but I can't figure about how. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: You'll need a back-end language, first of all. PHP, Python, Node.js, or Ruby are all fine choices.  Also, videos are pretty big, so you'll want a cheap way of storing them. You might want to look into Amazon's S3 storage.

Comment: Can't I do it with javascript only?

Comment: And the part about auto-generating pages? What language do I need? @vinayakj

Comment: For generating the pages with DB content you still need a backend language. You should dive into Node.js since you already have a JS foundation.

Comment: As said before, auto-generating pages will need a back-end language. You will need to learn one or two too.

Answer (score 1):

I note that you asked: "Can't I do it with javascript only?". Yes, you can!

You will need:

- Web Server => [Node](https://nodejs.org/) and [Express](http://expressjs.com/) is a choice.
- Database => [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) and [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) would be recommended.
- Client => [Video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) is great for your needs and also [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [MDL](http://www.getmdl.io/) are great frameworks (among many others). Also if your application starts getting too complicated you can use [Angular](https://angularjs.org/).

Of course all these technologies require hours and hours (and more hours) to master them, but there are tons of examples and the community here to help you.

Good luck and before you start I would advise you to "unknow" that it won't be famous.

Comment: Thanks a lot man :) I don't know most of them but I will learn them :) About the famous part if I made a general video sharing site I am pretty sure no one will leave youtube for my site, so I will just focus on one topic. Thanks again. Have a nice day :)